# Overriding values of Machine.config in web.config in .net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-config, machine.config

I am using .net 4.5 ASP.NET Web API application. How can i overwrite following settings in web.config file.

```
•maxWorkerThreads
•minWorkerThreads
•maxIoThreads
•minFreeThreads
•minLocalRequestFreeThreads
•maxconnection
•executionTimeout
```

Comment: Normally, the web.config values will take precedence over the machine.config values.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178685(v=vs.140)#the-processmodel-element

It states:

> Thus, processModel settings can be placed only in the Machine.config file, and they cannot be overridden by settings in any Web.config file.

Some of the settings you mentioned are part of this `processModel` and so cannot be modified via web.config.